# How to define type of destructured argument in .map

Tags: typescript

I have a destructured argument inside a `map` function:

```js
array.map(([name, data], index:number) => (
    console.log(name + data)
))
```

How can I set `name` and `data` as `name: string`, `data: object`?

Comment: Side note: `map` is not a generic iterator function, it's a **mapping** function. If you're not using the array that it creates and returns, don't use `map`. Use `forEach` or a `for` loop or a `for-of` loop, etc. instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way would be for `array` to have the correct type:

```
declare let array: Array<[string, object]>
array.map(([name, data], index:number) => (
    console.log(name + data)
))
```

You can also put the annotation on the destructuring expression:

```
declare let array: Array<any>
array.map(([name, data]: [string, object], index:number) => (
    console.log(name + data)
))
```

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, do it by making sure that `array` has a type, because then TypeScript will correctly infer the types of `name` and `data`. For example, here `array` has a type, so the types are inferred correctly:

```typescript
const array = [
    ["example", {}],
];
const result = array.map(([name, data], index) => {
    console.log(name, data);
});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwXAnjAvDA2gKBv7AIgFMAPOAWwAcAbYwgGhkIDc4aBXegXQZ24DcOUJFgJiEDjViZEyFADoKcKgApVWMJWJMAJnChxeMAJZhdZAJQYAfDADeeAiIgg6CmiADmqrRR0w+oaWQgC+IUA) *(note that you also don't need the type on `index`, since `map`'s type says what it is)*

As a second-best option, you can declare the type after the destructuring:

```typescript
const result = array.map(([name, data]: [string, object], index:number) => {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    console.log(name, data);
});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEEQBd6xlAngLjQO0wG0BdAbgCgwB7PAZ1TloFcJUBeNGDTAOgFsoABwAUwwnih8QAGnjAoyKMVyF6MAJZ4A5rLWatxWZtAAPAJTw2APngBvcvEfxqdKkh4QqW4RKmz5imYUAL5B5EA)